# Cannot import com.android.internal.app in Eclipse

Tags: android, import, internal

I cannot import com.android.internal.app in Eclipse. I created Android Project, but those apps are invisible. Should I change something in projet properties?

I want to import:

import com.android.internal.app.AlertActivity;
import com.android.internal.app.AlertController;

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

`com.android.internal.*` classes are internal classes of the Android Framework that are not intended to be public and thus they are not visible in the Android SDK. Those classes are subject to change from the Android Team without notice to developer. It is not recommend to use them for developing application as it is very likely that you app will be broken in the next Android release.